# Enumeration of a Dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary

I was given the following code to return an enumeration of the elements of a dictionary.

```
public class ArrayDictionary extends Dictionary implements Cloneable {
    protected Object[] keys ;
    protected Object[] values;
    protected int incr;
    protected int nelems;

    public Enumeration elements() {
        return new ArrayEnumeration(values,nelems);
    }
```

ArrayEnumeration is not defined within the rest of the code, none of the methods that are defined take an Array of Objects[] and an int, we're expected to do code inspection, and the way the question is written implies we shouldn't add new methods, I'll post the full code below. The only solution my friend and I can come up with is using a for loop to go through each item in the dictionary and use the get method that is defined?

Edit: There may be many other errors in the code we've not been through it all yet, as we can't get round this problem.

```
public class ArrayDictionary extends Dictionary implements Cloneable {
    /** The array of keys */
    protected Object[] keys ;

    /** The array of corresponding values */
    protected Object[] values ;

    /** How many real elements are in */
    protected int nelems ;

    /** By how much to grow */
    protected int incr ;

    /**
     * Create an ArrayDictionary using default values for initial size and
     * increment.
     */
    public ArrayDictionary() {
    this(10,10) ;
    }

    /**
     * Create an ArrayDictionary using the given initial size.
     * (The increment is set to the same value).
     * @param init The initial size
     */
    public ArrayDictionary(int init) {
    this(init,init) ;
    }

    /**
     * Clone this array dictionary.
     * <p>As for hashtables, a shallow copy is made, the keys and elements
     * themselves are <em>not</em> cloned.
     * @return The clone.
     */

    public Object clone() {
    try {
        ArrayDictionary cl = (ArrayDictionary) super.clone();
        cl.values = new Object[values.length];
        System.arraycopy(values, 0, cl.values, 0, values.length);
        cl.keys = new Object[values.length];
        System.arraycopy(keys, 0, cl.keys, 0, keys.length);
        return cl;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
        throw new InternalError();
    }
    }

    /**
     * Create an ArrayDictionary using the given initial size and
     * the given increment for growing the array.
     * @param init the initial size
     * @param incr the increment
     */
    public ArrayDictionary(int init, int incr) {
    keys = new Object[init] ;
    values = new Object[init] ;
    this.incr = incr ;
    nelems = 0 ;
    }

    /**
     * Create an ArrayDictionary, contructing the arrays of keys and
     * values from the two given vectors.
     * The two vectors should have the same size.
     * The increment is set to the number of elements.
     * @param keys the vector of keys
     * @param values the vector of values
     */
    public ArrayDictionary(Vector keys,Vector values) {
    this(keys,values,values.size()) ;
    }
    /**
     * Create an ArrayDictionary, contructing the arrays of keys and
     * values from the two given vectors.
     * The two vectors should have the same size.
     * @param keys the vector of keys
     * @param values the vector of values
     * @param incr the increment for growing the arrays
     */
    public ArrayDictionary(Vector keys, Vector values, int incr) {
    this.incr = incr ;
    nelems = keys.size() ;
    this.keys = new Object[nelems] ;
    this.values = new Object[nelems] ;
    keys.copyInto(this.keys) ;
    values.copyInto(this.values) ;
    }

    /**
     * Create an ArrayDicitonary, <em>using</em> (not copying) the given pair
     * of arrays as keys and values. The increment is set to the length of the
     * arrays. 
     * @param keys the array of keys
     * @param values the array of values
     */
    public ArrayDictionary(Object[] keys, Object[] values) {
    this(keys,values,values.length) ;
    }

    /**
     * Create an ArrayDicitonary, <em>using</em> (not copying) the given pair
     * of arrays as keys and values.
     * @param keys the array of keys
     * @param values the array of values
     * @param incr the increment for growing the arrays
     */
    public ArrayDictionary(Object[] keys, Object[] values, int incr) {
    this.incr = incr ;
    nelems = keys.length ;
    this.keys = keys ;
    this.values = values ;
    }

    protected final void grow() {
    grow(keys.length+incr) ;
    }

    protected void grow(int newCapacity) {
    Object[] newKeys = new Object[newCapacity] ;
    Object[] newVals = new Object[newCapacity] ;

    System.arraycopy(keys,0,newKeys,0,keys.length) ;
    System.arraycopy(values,0,newVals,0,values.length) ;

    keys = newKeys ;
    values = newVals ;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an enumeration of the elements of the dictionary.
     * @return the enumeration
     */
    public Enumeration elements() {
        return new ArrayEnumeration(values,nelems);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value that maps to the given key.
     * @param key the key
     * @return the value
     */
    public Object get(Object key) {
    int n,i;
    for(i=0,n=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        if(n >= nelems)
        break ;
        if ( keys[i] == null )
        continue;
        if(keys[i].equals(key)) 
        return values[i] ;
        n++ ;
    }
    return null;
    }

    /**
     * "Optimized" method to obtain the values
     * corresponding to several keys, in one swoop.
     * @param rKeys An array of requested keys
     * @return An array of corresponding values
     */
    public Object[] getMany(Object[] rKeys) {
    Object[] rValues = new Object[rKeys.length] ;
    int i,n ;
    for(i=0,n=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        if(n >= nelems) break ;
        if(keys[i]==null)
        continue ;
    inloop:
        for(int j=0;j<rKeys.length;j++) 
        if(keys[i].equals(rKeys[j])) {
            rValues[j] = values[i] ;
            break inloop ;
        }

        n++ ;
    }
    return rValues ;
    }


    /**
     * Are there any entries in the dictionary?
     * @return <strong>true</strong> if there are no entries,
     *         <strong>false></strong> otherwise.
     */
    public final boolean isEmpty() {
    return nelems==0 ;
    }

    /**
     * Increases the capacity of this dictionary to at least the
     * specified number of key/value mappings.
     * @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
     */
    public final void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    if(minCapacity>keys.length) grow(minCapacity) ;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an enumeration of the keys of the dictionary.
     * @return the enumeration
     */
    public Enumeration keys() {
    return new ArrayEnumeration(keys,nelems) ;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a mapping between a key and a value to the dictionary.
     * Will grow the arrays if necessary.
     * @param key the key
     * @param value the corresponding value
     * @return the previous value corresponding to the key, or null if
     *         the key is new.
     */
    public Object put(Object key,Object value) {
    int empty = -1 ;
    int i,n ;
    for(i=0,n=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        if(n >= nelems)
        break ;
        if(keys[i] == null) {
        empty = i ;
        continue ;
        }
        if(keys[i].equals(key)) {
        Object prev = values[i] ;
        values[i]=value;
        return prev ;
        }
        n++ ;
    }

    if(empty!=-1) {
        keys[empty]=key ;
        values[empty]=value ;
        nelems++ ;
    } else {
        grow() ;
        keys[nelems] = key ;
        values[nelems++] = value ;
    }

    return null ;
    }

    /**
     * Removes a key (and its value) from the dictionary;
     * @param key the key to remove
     * @return the value that used to map to that key
     */
    public Object remove(Object key) {
    int i,n ;
    for(i=0,n=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        if(n >= nelems)
        break ;
        if(keys[i] == null)
        continue ;
        if(keys[i].equals(key)) {
        nelems-- ;
        Object prev = values[i] ;
        keys[i] = values[i] = null ;
        return prev ;
        }
        n++ ;
    }
    return null ;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in the dictionary
     * @return the number of elements
     */
    public final int size() { return nelems ; }

    /**
     * Returns the maximum number of keys the dictionary can hold
     * without reallocating an array.
     * @return the capacity of the dictionary
     */
    public final int capacity() { return keys.length ; } 

    /**
     * Returns the nth key.
     * @param n the index of the desired key
     * @return the nth key, or null if no key in that place.
     */
    public final Object keyAt(int n) {
    return keys[n] ;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the nth element (value).
     * @param n the index of the desired element
     * @return the nth element, or null if no element in that place.
     */
    public final Object elementAt(int n) {
    return values[n] ;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the element at the nth place in the array.
     * @param n the index of the element to change
     * @param newVal the value to change it to
     * @return the old value
     */
    public Object setElementAt(int n,Object newVal) {
    Object prev = values[n] ;
    values[n] = newVal ;
    return prev ;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the nth mapping (key/value pair) in the dictionary.
     * @param n the index of the element to remove
     * @return the old value of the element at the nth place
     */
    public Object removeElementAt(int n) {
    if(values[n]!=null) {
        Object prev = values[n] ;
        values[n] = keys[n] = null ;
        nelems--;
        return prev;
    } else return null ;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a string representation of the dictionary
     * @return the string representation.
     */
    public String toString() {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(100) ;
    buf.append('[') ;
    for(int i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        if(keys[i]==null)
        continue ;
        buf.append(keys[i]) ;
        buf.append('=') ;
        buf.append(values[i]) ;
        buf.append(' ') ;
    }
    buf.append(']') ;
    return buf.toString() ;

    }
}
```

Comment: where is that code coming from??

Comment: Our lecturer provided it, I'm almost certain it's not his however, and it's just being used for this code inspection exercise.